# Export Prestashop products

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I need to export all Products in Prestashop to an Excel file. I built the module to export it to an Excel file. But the SQL query I am using is lacking some fields. Is anyone there to help me to get the following fields from the database ?

```
ID, TITLE, Quantity, Out of Stock, Quantity(min), Price, Date Added,
Last Modified Date, (plus all feature values)
```

Comment: Would you supply in your question the code you've already tried, so people can see how best to help you?

Comment: `SELECT 
P.id_product AS ID,
PL.name AS 'TITLE',
P.quantity AS Quantity,
P.out_of_stock AS Out of Stock,
P.minimal_quantity AS Quantity(min),
P.price as Price,
P.date_add AS Date Added,
P.date_upd AS Last Modified 

FROM ps_product AS P INNER JOIN ps_product_lang AS PL ON P.id_product = PL.id_product 

WHERE PL.id_lang = 2`

This is the code  I am using for now. I need to retrive all features of the the products as well.

Comment: `P.out_of_stock AS Out of Stock` won't work in any database I know - you need to specify quotes around a field if you absolutely must have spaces. So you need "feature values" - is that in a separate table across several rows? Do you want to specify them in a single row, against the product-level fields in your export? Do you have an entity relationship diagram for your db you can refer (us) to?

Comment: I am expecting someone who knows Prestashop to answer this question.

Comment: Np, good luck! s/expecting/hoping for/ `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

This is the format you are after - you'll need to chop and change the fields (look at your db in phpmyadmin or similar to get column titles/tables) to get exactly what you are after:

```
SELECT p.`id_product`, price, `name`, `description`, `link_rewrite`
FROM `ps_product` as p
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` pl ON (pl.`id_product` = p.`id_product`) 
WHERE pl.`id_lang`= 1 GROUP BY p.`id_product`';
```